# Know from where and which access key an EC2 instance being launched by?

Tags: amazon-ec2

Is there a way to know from which IP and with which secret key someone launching your EC2 instance by?

Comment: If someone else is launching EC2 instances in your account, you should be revoking all keys and contact AWS Support so they can begin locking the whole thing down.

Comment: Amazon contacted me this morning warning about some suspicious access.  I have already revoked all keys but trying to figure out how did someone gain access.

Comment: I've seen some folks get compromised because they accidentally committed their access keys to a Github repo. Lots of folks wanting to mine cryptocurrencies with others' money.

Answer (score 1):

This won't help you with API actions that have already occurred, but you should enable [Cloudtrail](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/). This enables detailed logging of all API actions, including key ID as well as source IP address.

Comment: How to enable Cloudtrail?

Comment: Read the documentation. It's very simple.